# python error discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter a command, it gives an error in the bot console, I want to make a level system, but an error pops up.

The code itself:

class Levels(commands.Cog):
def **init**(self, client):
self.client = client

```
    with open(r"path\to\json\file\users.json", "r") as f:
        self.users = json.load(f)

    self.client.loop.create_task(self.save_users())

async def save_users(self):
    await self.client.wait_until_ready()
    while not self.client.is_closed():
        with open(r"path\to\json\file\users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(self.users, f, indent=4)

        await asyncio.sleep(5)

def lvl_up(self, author_id):
    cur_xp = self.users[author_id]["exp"]
    cur_lvl = self.users[author_id]["level"]

    if cur_xp >= round((4 * (cur_lvl ** 3)) / 5):
        self.users[author_id]["level"] += 1
        return True
    else:
        return False

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.client.user:
        return

    author_id = str(message.author.id)

    if not author_id in self.users:
        self.users[author_id] = {}
        self.users[author_id]["level"] = 0
        self.users[author_id]["exp"] = 0

    self.users[author_id]["exp"] += 1

    if self.lvl_up(author_id):
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is now level {self.users[author_id]['level']}")

@bot.command(brief="Displays the user's level and experience.")
async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    member_id = str(member.id)

    if not member_id in self.users:
        await ctx.send(f"{member} doesn't have a level")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.set_author(name=f"Member = {member}", icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name="Level", value=self.users[member_id]["level"])
        embed.add_field(name="XP", value=self.users[member_id]["exp"])

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(Levels(client))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The line
`@bot.command(brief="Displays the user's level and experience.")`
needs to be
`@commands.command(brief="Displays the user's level and experience.")`
because you are inside a cog